# Response.Redirect no longer opening network file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got an ASP.NET site which allows users to view/open files from a shared network folder via links which call response.redirect passing in the full location of the relevant file (using a mapped drive value on appserver, not specific server name).
This works fine in IE7 but now w're doing a Win7 upgrade it isn't working in IE9 (or Chrome). For IE9 it displays basic "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage" message.

I've tried changing it to pass in the path using server instead of mapped drive but that's worse, is tries to start at root of application directory and then acts as if server is a folder within it (and displays "The page cannot be found").

The site probably shoudln't have ever been designed in this way but I need a dirty workaround, no time for complete redesign. Any ideas? If the cause is how newer browsers handle the redirect response is it possible to alter an advanced setting to mimic previous version? I've tried adding site as trusted and also compatibility view.

Sample code:

```
Response.Redirect("R:\SharedFolder\indexedEmail.msg"); //Where R is mapped to netshare
```

Comment: `Response.Redirect("Valid URL"), i.e not a file location`

Comment: Can the server side code open the file and stream it back from the request? That way you are not dependent on the behavior of the browser on how it handles local paths.

Comment: How bout trying a file URL prefix ?  file://

Comment: It's working with file://. I've tested on IE7, IE9 and Chrome.  That will require me to alter the file path settings of bespoke email indexer (file path is stored in database entry, so many complications!). Do you know if there is any way to leave these and alter how newer browsers handle Response.Redirect so that it will open files as before?

Comment: It wouldn't be a complete redesign to add 3 lines of code, would it?  Instead of Response.Redirect, use Resposne.WriteFile.  Then you won't have to deal with the browser issues.

Comment: Very true Rick, that phrasing was in anticipation of people recommending such. The problem is that even a small code change is problematic (I've inherited a lot of these applications and there's build issues with every single one, small and fixable but time consuming) and if I need to alter and release code changes for every system that encounters this issue then it's unmanageable. From responses so far it sounds like it's not possible to do a workaround  that meets my needs, so if anyone wants to add an answer recommending the file:// version I'll accept that as that's what I'm going with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using using the file:// URL prefix. The newer browsers may not be assuming that the URL is pointing to the local file system.